# MQL4 DLL Using Nugent and VB.net

Tags: vb.net, dll

I'm putting together a dll for use with MQL4 using nugent and vb.net and it's going pretty good so far.

In my dll I am setting a flag when a condition is met so that I don't have to keep checking each time the function is called. This works fine but what I realize it that the flag is remaining set and in memory even if I remove the EA that created the dll from the chart.

The flag is declared within a function in the module as static.

If I close the terminal and then open it again the flag has gone and the process starts again.

How can I remove the dll from memory and release it's resources (the static variable) on removal of the EA?

I'm thinking it should maybe call a function in the deinit but I can't find any VB.net examples of a dll 'killing' itself.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Steve

Update: I just had a thought. Maybe the dll is not supposed to end on removal of the EA from the chart? Could it be like that by design? If so I can just set the flag to false manually I guess.

But wouldn't that mean that if I add the EA to the chart again there will be another instance of the dll?

If anybody has a definitive answer though that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

DLLs to be used in MQL4 expose functions that can extend the functionality offered by MT4. From what i understand about DLLs, they DO NOT offer data retention. Like, in your case, when you call a function of the DLL in your MT4 code, the data is retained for the duration of that call. When you restart the EA, the data is gone and everything is back to default values.

Hope this helps.